# Set default value in MultiSelectListPreference

Tags: android

I want to check default value in MultiSelectListPreference from code.
I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15628558/how-to-set-multiple-default-values-in-a-multiselectlistpreference) but did not find any solution.
Please suggest a way to do it.

> ```
>     if (notificatinType != null) {
>         multi_list_preference.setEntries(notificatinType);
>     }
>     if (notificationTypeValue != null) {
>         multi_list_preference.setEntryValues(notificationTypeValue);
>     }
>     Boolean[] entryChecked = { true, false, true };
>     //String tryCheck = "[1, 2]";
>     multi_list_preference.setDefaultValue(entryChecked);        
>     if (notificationSelected != null) {
>         multi_list_preference.setDefaultValue(entryChecked);
>     }
> ```

Comment: I've only been able to get MultiSelectPreference to work with string arrays.